# Como mantenho elementos html na mesma linha

Tags: html

Bom teoricamente a minha pergunta é a seguinte, eu criei duas divs em html, contudo ao fazer a segunda, a segunda div não fica na mesma "linha" que a outra mas sim fica por baixo. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma tag em html que mantém os elementos todos na mesma linha, sem necessitação há margin-top do css.

Obrigado.

Comment: Mostre seu código pf.

Comment: `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Não sei se compreendi bem, mas parece que tu precisa de float:left na div, porém tem que ter certeza que o width das duas, somados, não fica maior que o width total disponível.

<div id="maior" style="width:600px;">

<div id="menor_esquerda" style="width:290px; margin-right:10px; background-color:#f00; float:left;"></div>

<div id="menor_direita" style="width:290px; float:left; background-color:#00f"></div>
 
</div>

Comment: Usar `<span>` ao invés de `<div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta não é muito especifica. Por isso não é possível dar uma resposta concreta, mas tentarei responder generalizado. 
A tag div quando é criada por padrão tem o atributo em css "display:block".
Se colocar em css.:

```
div{
   display:inline;
}
```

Todas as tags div vão ter essa característica, portanto ficaram na mesma linha.
Também pode "configurar".:

```
div{
   float:left;
}
```

Assim, desde que as divs consigam estar na mesma linha ficam seguidas, se não existir espaço vão para a linha abaixo.

Dependendo do objetivo pode também usar tabela.

Answer (score 1):

Existe a propriedade `display` dos elementos, e algumas tags já possuem um valor padrão para essa propriedade. O caso mais simples é que a `<div>` tem `display:block` e o `<span>` possui `display:inline` .

Não recomendo ficar alterando essa propriedade se já temos tags com nomes diferentes para identificar a função de cada uma.

Para ter uma referência um pouco melhor, dê uma lida http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp